# Override image constructor in JS?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to override the `Image` constructor in JS? So that, for example, every time a `new Image()` is created, a message is written to the console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```js
(function () {
    var OriginalImage = window.Image;
    window.Image = function (width, height) {
        console.log('New image');
        return new OriginalImage(width, height);   
    }
}());
```

Not sure if it will work in all browsers.

Anyway it is not best idea to override built in types (unless you want to use it to mock/stub for test purposes).

Comment: This worked in FF, only thing I'd add is that the Image object can take in an optional width and height parameter.

Comment: Updated to provide width and height :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/02/javascript-override-patterns.html) link, it is possible to override constructors. However, I believe this is now what you want, you want to EXTEND it. Take a look at the "Extends ABC" part.