# shorthand for associative array of Image objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I wanted to make an *associative array* in Javascript in which I would have a bunch of string keys pointing to `Image` objects.  The reason for this, is I wanted to go about pre-loading and dynamically controlling a lot of images without polluting the global space with hundreds of global variables.  For example, to avoid the following:

```
var img1, img2, img3, ... , img99; 
img1 = img2 = img3 = ... = img99 = new Image();
```

Instead, I just wanted to call the image by some identifiable string name, to make the code easier to read, and to only have one `_images` variable in the global space.

At first, I attempted to use an `Array` for this task, only to find that there was no syntax for specifying instantiation of an `Array` with string keys.  Further investigation led me [here](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/) which went as far as to say that `Array` being used as an *associative array* could be harmful.

Previously, I had assumed that Javascript arrays were similar to *LUA tables* in which there was an indexed portion (whose size was kept in the `length` attribute) and a *hash* portion (string indexed).  Apparently, that is not the case.  Instead, when specifying a "string key" it is actually just shorthand for specifying an *object attribute*.

Thus, I was finally led down this path:

```
var _images = {
    "button_mouseover": new Image(),
    "button_mouseout": new Image(),
    "button_mousedown": new Image(),
    "button_mouseup": new Image()       
}
```

In which I create an object (whose reference is stored in `_images`) with a series of properties each storing a reference to an instantiated `Image` object.

Now to populate the `src` attribute of all the images, is to say the least, quite verbose:

```
_images["button_mouseover"].src = "fsfs.gif";
_images["button_mouseout"].src = "gsgs.gif";
_images["button_mousedown"].src = "agag.gif";
_images["button_mouseup"].src = "ggg.gif";
```

Finding the non-w3schools specs on the `Image` constructor, *a default type*, was hard in itself (there was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936071/where-are-constructors-such-as-new-image-and-new-option-documented) on where it was!).  Apparently, the constructor only takes an optional `width` and `height`, but no source attribute.

So, naturally, the next route I considered was the possibility of *extending* the `Image` constructor so that I could perhaps shorten this up a bit to:

```
var _images = {
    "button_mouseover": new Image("fsfs.gif"),
    "button_mouseout": new Image("gsgs.gif"),
    "button_mousedown": new Image("agag.gif"),
    "button_mouseup": new Image("ggg.gif")      
}
```

This led me to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717226/override-image-constructor-in-js).  The stigma there seemed to be, that it was possible, but not likely to work in all browsers and that extending *default types* is taboo.

That brings me to my questions then:

1. Is *extending* the `Image` constructor really not going to work in some browsers?
2. Is there some other Javascript object notation to do this that I've overlooked?

OR

Am I just stuck with having to list all the attributes, new Image() calls, and then a whole separate section with listing all the keys and sources again?

OR

Should I just use an *auxiliary function*, such as this:

```
function Image2( src ) {
    var t = new Image();
    t.src = src;
    return t;   
}

var _images = {
    "button_mouseover": Image2("fsfs.gif"),
    "button_mouseout": Image2("gsgs.gif"),
    "button_mousedown": Image2("agag.gif"),
    "button_mouseup": Image2("ggg.gif")     
}
```

Comment: I guess my question is, why do you need to use a constructor function at all? What do you have in mind for the image objects after you've created them and assigned them to your hash?

Comment: I think you are searching for something called a loop. [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) perhaps?

Comment: `Further investigation led me here which went as far as to say that Array being used as an associative array could be harmful.` **Yes, absolutely.** The `Array` type is a special case of `Object` for numeric-keyed dense arrays. Use just the `Object` type for the "associative arrays" concept.

Comment: @Jon I can't really `for..in` against the `_images` object because I'm not really sure what all default properties are assigned to it (if any) and each image `src` is invariably unique so looping through each property for assignment would be sketchy at best for if I created a simple array of `src` values and assigned them in the `for..in` I'm not really sure if I'm guaranteed the [correct order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-in-a-for-in-loop) etc but maybe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The auxiliary function is probably your best bet, as it groups all the repeat code into a function.

Personally, I would do something like:

```
(function() {
    var img = function(src) {
        var t = new Image();
        t.src = src;
        return t;
    };
    window._images = {
        "over": img("fsfs.gif"),
        "out": img("gsgs.gif"),
        "down": img("agag.gif"),
        "up": img("ggg.gif")
    };
})();
```

Having shorter property names can help keep code reasonably-sized without losing too much readability, too.

Comment: I hadn't considered grouping them together into a single, immediately invoked _anonymous_ function.  I think that perhaps this was the capstone I was looking for regarding this issue.  I know my question was vague at best, but I really like what you did with it here.

Comment: It doesn't even need to be anonymous, or "immediately invoked". Just a normal function would do.

Comment: Right, but I think the advantage of this route is that I don't add an extra variable in the global space (e.g. the name I assign to the auxiliary function) that could inadvertently affect something else.

Answer (score 1):

The latter solution is the nicest one.  Javascript objects are equivalent to associative arrays, or hash tables.  Alternatively you can use a functional library like [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) to map the array:

```
var refs = {
  "button_mouseover": "fsfs.gif",
  "button_mouseout": "gsgs.gif",
  "button_mousedown": "agag.gif",
  "button_mouseup": "ggg.gif"     
}
var _images = _.map(refs, function(value) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = value;
  return image;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the underscore library, I'm sure it'll help some.  I don't think I need to go that far with this, though.

Comment: Isn't `map` a native function? Or rather, when was it not? (Obviously I guess earlier browsers didn't have it?)

Comment: @Kolink EMCAScript5 added 'map' for arrays, I haven't seen anything about Objects however.